# All public member functions of user-defined exception declared with throw()?

Tags: c++

Is it a good practice to have all member functions of user-defined exceptions declared with `throw()`? e.g.

```
class MyCustomException : public std::exception 
{
public:
    MyCustomException(const std::string& message, const std::string& additional) : 
        message_(message), additional_(additional) {}

    virtual const char* what() const throw() { return message_.c_str(); }
    const char* additional() const throw() { return additional_.c_str(); }

    virtual ~MyCustomException() throw() {};

private:
    const std::string message_;
    const std::string additional_;
};
```

Here the `additional()` information reader would also be declared to `throw()` meaning that the function must not throw an exception.

Comment: C++11 has `noexcept`, destructor should be `noexcept`